# Efficient way to subtract 2 list in python with certain conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I Have 2 lists

```py
A=[1,1.5,2.3,4,5] 
B=[1.6,2.6,3.3,4.4,5.5]
```

I want to do `B-A` such that index `i` of `B` gets subtracted from the index `(i+1)` of `A`, and if the value returned is positive then we will store the value else we will put `0`.

For the above case, the resultant list will look like

```py
C = [0, .1, .3, 0, 0]
```

Also, the `0`th index of the resultant list should always be `0`

Comment: Those are `lists` not arrays.

Comment: Shifting a list one position is simply taking a slice.  Where is the problem code and error?

Comment: If they were `ndarray`, `np.maximum(0, B[:-1]-A[1:]) ` takes care of everything except the initial 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `zip` here.

```
A=[1,1.5,2.3,4,5]
B=[1.6,2.6,3.3,4.4,5.5]
res=[0]+[round(x-y,1) if x-y>0 else 0 for x,y in zip(B,A[1:])]
print(res)
#[0, 0.1, 0.3, 0, 0]
```

---

For numpy arrays use `np.concatenate` and `np.maximum` as suggested in comments by @hpaulj.

```
import numpy as np
res=np.concatenate(([0],np.maximum(0, B[:-1]-A[1:])))
print(res)
#array([0. , 0.1, 0.3, 0. , 0. ])
```